# PHP Debug Bar Guzzle Integration

Tags: php, guzzle, phpdebugbar

What would be the best way to log all guzzle requests to the php debugbar?

Normally there would be some type of event that is fired which I could listen for and pass the data to a collector for the debug bar. However, guzzle doesn't seem to have any events. Instead it is using middle ware and handlers which I don't quite understand how I would integrate with the debugbar to log requests and timeline, execution duration info to the debug bar.

Comment: I'm using the newest version – guzzlehttp. Guzzle http doesn't have events.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have mostly figured this out.

I created my own middleware and registered it with the client.

Custom middleware.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\PromiseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Rocket\Cockpit\Facade\Container;
use Rocket\Moc\Debugbar\MocDebugBar;

class GuzzleHttpMiddleware {

    /** @var callable  */
    private $nextHandler;

    /**
     * @param callable $nextHandler Next handler to invoke.
     */
    public function __construct(callable $nextHandler) {
        $this->nextHandler = $nextHandler;
    }

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param array            $options
     *
     * @return PromiseInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(RequestInterface $request, array $options)
    {
        $fn = $this->nextHandler;
        $debugbar = Container::get(MocDebugBar::class);

        $debugbar['rest']->addRequest($request);

        return $fn($request, $options)
            ->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) use ($request, $options) {

                return $response;

            });

    }

}
```

Registering custom middleware with handler stack – PHP League container used.

```
// Register http client.
$this->getContainer()->share(Client::class,function() {

    // In theory this "should" be available
    $config = load_class('Config');

    // Add debugbar middleware to handler stack.
    $stack = HandlerStack::create();
    $stack->after('prepare_body',function(callable $handler) {
        return new GuzzleHttpMiddleware($handler);
    },'debugbar');

    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri'=> $config->item('service_url'),
        'handler'=> $stack,
    ]);

    return $client;
},true);
```

I was having a difficult time understanding the workflow of the handlers and promises until I actually looked into the promise library alone. Once I did that everything made much more sense.